# Why doesn’t my $getjson call working?

Tags: javascript, php, getjson

I’m relatively new to this php and I’m attempting to access/execute a php file from my javascript file and have it appear in my html. I was told $getjson is the best way to do that but I do not see my php script past backed into my html:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <div class="button"></div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
    <script src="Test.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>
<body>
     <a href="#" id="getdata-button">Get JSON Data</a>
    <div id="showdata"></div>
</body> 

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( document ).on("click","#getdata-button", function() {
    //test Confirmed
    alert('hello8');
       $.getJSON('Test.php', function(data) {
            //noresponse
            alert('hello5');
            $('#showdata').html("item1="+data.item1+" item2="+data.item2+" item3="+data.item3+"");
        });
    });
});
```

Test.php:

```
    < ?php
$items = array( 
  'item1' => 'I love jquery4u',
  'item2' => 'You love jQuery4u',
  'item3' => 'We love jQuery4u'
);

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($items);

?>
```

My expected result is to item1/item2/item3 in the html.

Comment: What goes wrong? What (if any) errors are reported in the console?

Comment: Is that jQuery? If so, what version? `.live()` has been gone for a long time. Aside from that, I don't see any issue unless there's something wrong with the PHP (I have no PHP experience).

Answer (score 1):

First make sure your javascript code really is triggered/executed.
http://api.jquery.com/live/ says:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

And then use something like

```
<?php // no space between < and ? or php
$items = array( 
  'item1' => 'I love jquery4u',
  'item2' => 'You love jQuery4u',
  'item3' => 'We love jQuery4u'
);
// the (configuarable) default for the content-type is text/html
// -> let the client "manually" know the response is json
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($items);
```

as your server-side script. (prints: `{"item1":"I love jquery4u","item2":"You love jQuery4u","item3":"We love jQuery4u"}`)

Comment: Thanks! I redid the Test.php file as request: < ?php
$items = array( 
  'item1' => 'I love jquery4u',
  'item2' => 'You love jQuery4u',
  'item3' => 'We love jQuery4u'
);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($items);
?>                                                                                                                 I also rewrote the the js file to the 1.7 method and confirm the call is executing but I am still not see the php script execute. Am I looking in the wrong place for the execution? I am executing this script from the html page directly.